# supervisord not including [include] files=/abs/path/to/files/*conf

Tags: linux, symfony, centos, rabbitmq, supervisord

I have a fresh install of supervisord inside a development vagrant machine. I have rabbitmq setup and receiving messages from my Symfony2 producers. I am attempting to use supervisord to maintain X consumers which are Symfony2 console commands.

The following config works like a dream. My consumers are created and maintained fine.

```
# /etc/supervisord.conf
# ...

[supervisord]
  logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
  user=root

[program:rabbitmq-consume-email]
  command=/usr/bin/php /another/path/app/console rabbitmq:consumer -w email
  numprocs=2
  process_name=%(program_name)s-%(process_num)s
```

But changing it up to the following, does not seem to create any producers, including checking for current consumers on the queues I am consuming from.

```
# /etc/supervisord.conf
# ...

[supervisord]
  logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
  user=root

[include]
  files = /abs/path/to/more/confs/*.conf
```

With ...

```
# /abs/path/to/more/confs/rabbitmq-email.conf
# ...

[program:rabbitmq-consume-email]
  command=/usr/bin/php /another/path/app/console rabbitmq:consumer -w email
  numprocs=2
  process_name=%(program_name)s-%(process_num)s
```

As you can see from the following, the configuration files all share the same permissions. But even making the included config files 777 (purely out of frustration) I have no progress.

```
vagrant@box  ~  ls -l /etc/supervisord.conf

  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 391 Dec  3 14:51 /etc/supervisord.conf

vagrant@box  ~  ls -l /abs/path/to/more/confs/

  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 197 Dec  3 15:41 rabbitmq-email.conf
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 193 Dec  3 15:42 rabbitmq-sms.conf
```

The log file shows the normal start info (at debug level) and no errors concerning including any files (before and after permission changes.

```
2015-12-03 16:00:02,225 CRIT Set uid to user 0
2015-12-03 16:00:02,234 DEBG supervisord forked; parent exiting
2015-12-03 16:00:02,235 INFO daemonizing the process
2015-12-03 16:00:02,235 INFO supervisord started with pid 28061
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: try launching a program as `supervisorctl start rabbitmq-consume-email`

Comment: in the conf of my process I have the following keys: `autostart=true` and 
 `autorestart=true` probably can affect to the autostart?

Comment: I added them and it hasn't helped... I am starting to lean towards a fresh vagrant box, incase something odd is going on with one of the dependencies.

Comment: Can you check the output of `supervisorctl status`? That should give you some clue on the different programs.

Comment: Any updates on this one ? I am having the same issue with no luck. Supervisor version 3.2.3 running on Centos 6.7

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. My consumer runs fine if I launch it from the shell. However via supervisord even though it seems to be running, it will not pick up any published messages.

Comment: If it helps anybody, the default config's [include] section is commented out by default. Remove the semicolon before it and it "magically" works :facepalm: I want that hour back.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in `[include]` section, supervisor is expecting relative paths, not absolute ones as we assume.

```
[include]
  files = ../../home/myuser/supervisor_confs/*.conf
```

In this example, my conf file is `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`.

and other conf files for each program i want to include are saved at `/home/myuser/supervisor_confs/`. I have to adjust the path to be a relative path to use in the `[include]` section